# How to change the default GCC compiler in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I have installed gcc-3.3/g++-3.3 on ubuntu 11.04 which already has gcc/g++-4.4. So in my system both gcc-3.3 and 4.4 are available. I am able to call both compilers as I want. If I just call the command `gcc` then gcc-4.4 will get called. To call gcc-3.3, I have to use the command `gcc-3.3`.

How can I change the default compiler as gcc-3.3? When I execute the command `gcc` it should call the gcc-3.3 and not gcc-4.4.

In addition, how can I change the variable CXX in a make file to gcc-3.3? I wish to change one common global place in the system instead of changing all make files.

Comment: For CXX flag you can invoke `CXX=gcc-3.3` or `export CXX=gcc-3.3` and then `make` however when you changed it globally with `update-alternatives` it will already use gcc-3.3 and this is not necessary.

Comment: @RoboAlex: updated my answer again to take into account your CXX environment variable request. However, please note that it will only serve in case you modify the update-alternatives later.

Comment: You only need to change your PATH. Most of the answers mention the alternatives system, but both the Debian and the LLVM maintainers agree that the *alternatives* system should be used for *alternatives*, NOT for *versioning*. Further explained in my answer.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

As @Tommy suggested, you should use `update-alternatives`.
It assigns values to every software of a family, so that it defines the order in which the applications will be called.

It is used to maintain different versions of the same software on a system. In your case, you will be able to use several declinations of `gcc`, and one will be favoured.

To figure out the current priorities of gcc, type in the command pointed out by @tripleee's comment:

```
update-alternatives --query gcc
```

Now, note the priority attributed to `gcc-4.4` because you'll need to give a higher one to `gcc-3.3`.
To set your alternatives, you should have something like this *(assuming your `gcc` installation is located at `/usr/bin/gcc-3.3`, and `gcc-4.4`'s priority is less than 50)*:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-3.3 50
```

*--edit--*

Finally, you can also use the interactive interface of `update-alternatives` to easily switch between versions. Type `update-alternatives --config gcc` to be asked to choose the gcc version you want to use among those installed.

*--edit 2 --*

Now, to fix the CXX environment variable systemwide, you need to put the line indicated by @DipSwitch's in your `.bashrc` file (this will apply the change only for your user, which is safer in my opinion):

```
echo 'export CXX=/usr/bin/gcc-3.3' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: @thang also called `cc`:
`root@host:/root# update-alternatives --get-selections | grep '/usr/bin/gcc'
cc                             auto     /usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: When I run the 'update-alternatives --config gcc', nothing happens, even though I have the system's gcc and anaconda one

Comment: how could you do this automatically though? this requires a manual step to check the output of `update-alternatives --query gcc`, which might not work eg in an automated provisioning script. Also, how can this be made platform agnostic?

Answer (score 79):

Here's a complete example of jHackTheRipper's answer for the TL;DR crowd. :-) In this case, I wanted to run g++-4.5 on an Ubuntu system that defaults to 4.6. As `root`:

```
apt-get install g++-4.5
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6 100
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.5 50
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 100
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.5 50
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp-bin /usr/bin/cpp-4.6 100
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp-bin /usr/bin/cpp-4.5 50
update-alternatives --set g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.5
update-alternatives --set gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.5
update-alternatives --set cpp-bin /usr/bin/cpp-4.5
```

Here, 4.6 is still the default (aka "auto mode"), but I explicitly switch to 4.5 temporarily (manual mode). To go back to 4.6:

```
update-alternatives --auto g++
update-alternatives --auto gcc
update-alternatives --auto cpp-bin
```

(Note the use of `cpp-bin` instead of just `cpp`. Ubuntu already has a `cpp` alternative with a master link of `/lib/cpp`. Renaming that link would remove the `/lib/cpp` link, which could break scripts.)

Comment: For the lazy person of the future trying to set the installed g++-5 compiler to be default: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 100`

Comment: Only 1 question remains: why won't APT do this when installing the `g++-6` package?

Comment: I switched the default compiler to g++-5 this way, but it still uses g++-7 standard libraries, and now i'm getting errors with undefined `__builtin` stuff.

Answer (score 28):

[This is the great description](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/) and step-by-step instruction how to create and manage master and slave (gcc and g++) alternatives.

Shortly it's:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.7
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

Comment: what's with the 40 and 60. I am trying to use gcc-6.

Comment: @nyxee 40 and 60 denote the priority assigned to each entry, check the other answers for more completeness on the topic

Answer (score 15):

Between 4.8 and 6 with all `--slaves`:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 \
                    10 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-4.8 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/gcov-dump gcov-dump /usr/bin/gcov-dump-4.8 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/gcov-tool gcov-tool /usr/bin/gcov-tool-4.8 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/gcc-ar gcc-ar /usr/bin/gcc-ar-4.8 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/gcc-nm gcc-nm /usr/bin/gcc-nm-4.8 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib gcc-ranlib /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-4.8
```

and

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 \
                    15 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/gcc-6 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/g++-6 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-6 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/gcov-dump gcov-dump /usr/bin/gcov-dump-6 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/gcov-tool gcov-tool /usr/bin/gcov-tool-6 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/gcc-ar gcc-ar /usr/bin/gcc-ar-6 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/gcc-nm gcc-nm /usr/bin/gcc-nm-6 \
                    --slave   /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib gcc-ranlib /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-6
```

Change between them with `update-alternatives --config gcc`.

Comment: works fine after removing `cc` and `c++`  lines, which cause error: alternative cc can't be slave of gcc: it is a master alternative

Comment: This is the right approach. All GCC utilities should be configured.

Answer (score 7):

Now, there is gcc-4.9 available for Ubuntu/precise.

Create a group of compiler alternatives where the distro compiler has a higher priority:

```
root$ VER=4.6 ; PRIO=60
root$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-$VER $PRIO --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-$VER
root$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp-bin /usr/bin/cpp-$VER $PRIO

root$ VER=4.9 ; PRIO=40
root$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-$VER $PRIO --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-$VER
root$ update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cpp cpp-bin /usr/bin/cpp-$VER $PRIO
```

**NOTE:** g++ version is changed automatically with a gcc version switch. cpp-bin has to be done separately as there exists a "cpp" master alternative.

List available compiler alternatives:

```
root$ update-alternatives --list gcc
root$ update-alternatives --list cpp-bin
```

To select manually version 4.9 of gcc, g++ and cpp, do:

```
root$ update-alternatives --config gcc
root$ update-alternatives --config cpp-bin
```

Check compiler versions:

```
root$ for i in gcc g++ cpp ; do $i --version ; done
```

Restore distro compiler settings (here: back to v4.6):

```
root$ update-alternatives --auto gcc
root$ update-alternatives --auto cpp-bin
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this problem while trying to install a new clang compiler. Turns out that both [the Debian](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2014/06/msg00381.html) and [the LLVM maintainers agree](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-3.1/+bug/991493/comments/33) that the alternatives system should be used for *alternatives,* NOT for *versioning*.

The solution they propose is something like this:
`PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-3.7/bin:$PATH`
where /usr/lib/llvm-3.7/bin is a directory that got created by the llvm-3.7 package, and which contains all the tools with their non-suffixed names. With that, llvm-config (version 3.7) appears with its plain name in your PATH. No need to muck around with symlinks, nor to call the llvm-config-3.7 that got installed in /usr/bin.

Also, check for a package named llvm-defaults (or gcc-defaults), which might offer other way to do this (I didn't use it).

Comment: Excellent solution ! Me use it to for selecting amongst custom built "gcc" suites

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a quicker (but still very clean) way of achieving it for a personal purpose (for instance if you want to build a specific project having some strong requirements concerning the version of the compiler), just follow the following steps:

- type `echo $PATH` and look for a *personal* directory having a very high priority (in my case, I have `~/.local/bin`);
- add the symbolic links in this directory:

For instance:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-WHATEVER ~/.local/bin/gcc
ln -s /usr/bin/g++-WHATEVER ~/.local/bin/g++
```

Of course, this will work for a single user (it isn't a system wide solution), but on the other hand I don't like to change too many things in my installation.

Comment: So you're creating your own ad-hoc, parallel-to-the-system's alternatives system. Why not use the real thing?

Comment: @hmijail As I explained, I use this way when I want to build a very single project without messing up my whole installation. It works very well and I can easely remove it after.

Comment: Just changing your PATH would be faster, cleaner and would keep your gcc-related tools in sync with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I used just the lines below and it worked. I just wanted to compile `VirtualBox` and `VMWare WorkStation` using `kernel 4.8.10` on `Ubuntu 14.04`. Initially, most things were not working for example graphics and networking. I was lucky that `VMWare workstation` requested for `gcc 6.2.0`. I couldn't start my `Genymotion Android emulators` because virtualbox was down. Will post results later if necessary.

```
VER=4.6 ; PRIO=60
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-$VER $PRIO --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-$VER
VER=6 ; PRIO=50
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-$VER $PRIO --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-$VER
VER=4.8 ; PRIO=40
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-$VER $PRIO --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-$VER
```