# How to install a newer version of gcc separately

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am using CentOS 5.6 which have gcc 4.1.2 installed. I want to *additionally* install gcc 4.4.6. So, basically I want to install it as a second gcc, and not upgrade the previous one (that is, I want to keep it). What is the simplest way to do so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7834049/643500 its for Ubuntu, but it should work for you

Comment: Is this the same box as your other question, where you do not have root access?

Comment: No I do have root access on this one. Will configure, make, make install do? In configure though I will have to prescribe a separate directory, such as --prefix=directory.

Comment: Yes, the only serious issue with root is that most distribution's package system for installing pre-built programs from the distribution only works for root, and insists on putting the package files in fixed, system-wide locations.  But you can build something from source for yourself and set an install location under your home directory.  Binaries distributed separately from a linux distro are often more flexible too.

Comment: The really tricky part in my opinion is getting a new GCC to use the currently installed libgcc and libstdc++ libraries. If you don't, you will be always limited to running your compiled programs on only that one machine.

Answer (score 1):

Just install gcc and the various libraries in a separate directory. Create a script to update the various environment variables (you will need to source this) to set the shell to use the appropriate version as required.

Comment: Yes, but most of the challenge is probably figuring out what exactly to install - a compatible but generic binary tarball?  Build it from generic or distribution source?   Install a distribution package, somehow convincing it to go in an alternate location? (FYI poster has a related question which seems to indicate they do not have root on the box - would have been good if that were mentioned explicitly here)

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Any of the above will work. Perhaps a tarball is the simplest in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You will generally need the gcc package itself, ideally a dedicated version of glibc, and then binutils (and perhaps more), and you will need to install them all to a common prefix.

You may want to look into projects such as buildroot as well (for a pre-made solution), or 'Linux From Scratch' which explains the process of building your normal toolchain).

Answer (score 0):

`yum install gcc44` did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps, I have tested them and worked correctly for me ([Install alternative version of gcc](https://www.hongliangjie.com/2012/07/20/how-to-install-gcc-higher-version-in-alternative-directory/))