# Make runs cc and I don't understand why

Tags: linux, makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.s)
BIN = $(SRC:.s=)

all: $(BIN)
    echo 4
```

There is an assembler file (fizzbuzz.s) in the current directory. When I do `make` command it runs

`cc    fizzbuzz.s   -o fizzbuzz`

and I don't understand why it is happenning? What is wrong?

**UPDATE**:

The same happens when I use another Makefile:

```
.PHONY: clean all

AS = nasm
LNK = ld 
SRC = $(wildcard *.s)
BIN := $(SRC:.s=)

all: $(BIN)

%: %.o
    $(LNK) -melf_i386 $< -o $@
%.o: %.s
    $(AS) -f elf $< -o $@
clean:
    rm -f $(BIN)
```

Comment: There are built-in default recipes, like using `cc` to compile `.s`

Comment: @Barmar, how can I change the behavior?

Comment: What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Your second makefile uses `nasm` for `.asm` files, not `.s` files.

Comment: [Make gcc the default compiler of make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051208/make-gcc-the-default-compiler-of-make) is not *quite* duplicative, but certainly relevant.

Comment: I suspect you'll get what you want if you simply change `%.asm` to `%.s`, or make the rule work with both suffixes. But since you haven't stated what the desired result is, it's not clear.

Comment: Yes, it works with `*.asm`, but why it doesn't work with `*.s`? nasm can compile the file with the extension. PS. Happy New Year!

Comment: I found the way to change the behavior https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603343/9210255
Thanks all!

Comment: Consider adding that as an answer -- unless you're okay with the question just being marked as a duplicate. (Let me know if it's the latter -- both Barmar and I hold dupehammers for the linux tag and can do that singlehandedly).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, OK, I will add the answer, but I need to understand why it is happening, so it takes some time.

Comment: Also see [Using Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) in the GNU Make manual.

Answer (score 3):

A simple answer is `make`'s behavior. But it doesn't give understanding how it works, so let's go deeper.

We begin with the first Makefile. Because my directory has only one file `fizzbuzz.s`, the variable `BIN` will be equal `fizzbuzz`. `Make` searches the `fizzbuzz` target, but there is no the target. For that reason `make` processes built-in rules. It searches files with extension added to `fizzbuzz` target and if it has searched the files it processes own rules. I tried to remove the Makefile and run command: `make fizzbuzz` and it runs another

`cc    fizzbuzz.s   -o fizzbuzz`.

It's equal to the first Makefile.

Now, we'll use the second Makefile.
When I changed the `.s` extension on `.asm` it worked. Interesting behavior, it's because `make` doesn't have built-in rules for `.asm` extension. I wanted to get understanding so I returned `.asm` to `.s` back.
My second Makefile has a rule for target without extension:

```
%: %.o
    $(LNK) -melf_i386 $< -o $@
```

But it doesn't work as expected and works like without Makefile. This happens, I suppose, because `%` has the last priority execution after built-in rules. We can change the behaviour by adding `MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules` in the Makefile, and everything works fine.

But I noted one weird thing without the option. I did the command `make fizzbuzz.o` and it has been built `fizzbuzz.o`(it processes command from my Makefile). So, OK. Let's run `make` again. I run it and it built me the final `fizzbuzz` target. Surprise!

So the rule

```
%: %.o
    $(LNK) -melf_i386 $< -o $@
```

is working when there are object files(.o) in the current directory. I don't know what it is, a bug or a feature(IMHO a weird feature), but it works so.

Finally, we have two solutions to make second Makefile working and they are the following:

- omit built-in rules by replacing `.s` extension by `.asm` or any other which doesn't have built-in rules in `make`
- disable built-in rules by adding to Makefile an option `MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules` or run with `make -R` or `make -r`