# cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’ while installing Cling in Ubuntu 12.04 using gcc 4.8

Tags: c++, ubuntu, c++11, gcc, cling

I am trying to install Cling(interactive C++ interpreter) from [here](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling-build-instructions) using the .sh file. While I run the .sh file in the terminal, I get the following errors:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’
```

Since the default gcc for 12.04 is 4.6.3, I updated to gcc 4.8 to help remove C++11 errors, then ran the following commands to check which version of gcc is being used for compilation

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I also tried to figure out the current priorities of gcc, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu),

```
update-alternatives --query gcc
Link: gcc
Status: auto
Best: /usr/bin/gcc-4.8
Value: /usr/bin/gcc-4.8

Alternative: /usr/bin/gcc-4.8
Priority: 50
```

But the `"cc1plus"` error still remains. Is there a way to resolve this to help me run Cling seamlessly? Thanks!

---

EDIT: Followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522387/std-c11-not-recognized-on-gcc-4-8-1) and also updated my g++ from default 4.6.3 to 4.8.1 and the dont see the C++11 error anymore.

Comment: To verify, you did run the configure option before running the make? They list it as: `./configure --enable-cxx11`

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on how to configure gcc for c++11? And should I also update my g++(4.6.3) to the latest version?

Comment: did you try compiling simple c++11 code using:-     g++ -std=c++11 sample.cpp from the terminal?

Comment: @ShivarajBhat -No, this error appeared when I ran the Cling shell script from the terminal.

Comment: Check the version of `g++` not `gcc`.

Comment: Thanks @MikeSeymour, I have updated gcc to 4.8.1 and the C++11 error seems to be resolved. But I get a makeall error now. Please see Edited question.

Comment: @Luminosity There's almost always an actually useful error message from the command that failed before "Error 2". Aside from that, it seems to be a completely different question from what you originally asked, and editing questions like that is generally not accepted here.