# How to remove gcc from Debian Jessie

Tags: testing, gcc, debian

How can I remove **gcc** from a **Debian Jessie** installation, or at least switch back to **gcc-4.8**?

**gcc-4.9-base** is not removable. If I try, I get lot of unresolved dependencies.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu

Comment: update-alternatives --config gcc results in 
"no alternatives for gcc"

Comment: `gcc-4.9-base` is almost empty, why would you care if it has to stay?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you share some more details about what you've tried and the errors it's causing?