# how to change the version of g++ in makefile

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, g++

i have on my ubuntu 15.10 g++ complier 5, and i installed g++-4.2, by default the system will use the last version.
How to choose in the makfile the right version
should i replace in the makefile the

```
cc=g++
```

by

```
cc=g-4.2
```

is that correct

Comment: If `g-4.2` is the name of the executable for GCC 4.2 then yes.

Comment: You can check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

If the g++ executable name (in `/usr/bin`) is `g++-4.2` then you can set `CC=g++-4.2` in the Makefile

Or you can create a link inside /usr/bin from `g++` to `g++-4.2` with this command:
`cd /usr/bin && sudo ln g++-4.3 g++`