# Installing OpenCV 3.2.0 with Python 2.7 in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-17.04

How can I install OpenCV 3.2.0 with Python 2.7 in Ubuntu 17.04? Is there any proper shell script for it?

I have tried [this](https://github.com/milq/milq) shell script. But I've got these errors. [image: errors]

Comment: Please copy terminal output instead of screenshotting it. It will help others with the same problem find this post

Comment: Try running `apt-get install build-essential` it depends on that, it might install it

Comment: @Igonato, I am sorry. I actually closed the terminal after taking the screen shot.

Comment: @Spammy23, I've tried your code. This message appeared, `build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the removal/relocation of `stdlib.h` in gcc-6. You can install gcc-5 and [make it the default compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu) (or config the CXX option in Cmake).