# R Error During Forecast Package Installation after CUDA-9.1 Upgrade on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: r, ubuntu, gcc, cuda

I was having difficulty running `install.packages("forecast")` after a new install of CUDA 9.1 on Ubuntu 17.10, with the error

```
#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 6 are not supported!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by first following [instructions here](https://iainhaslam.com/scraps/cuda-9-ubuntu-1710/) running from command line

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc
```

I then got the error

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

This is due to GCC 6 not having a G++ to go with it. Simply install G++6 with:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-6
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu) before recommending undesirable ways to manage software versions on ubuntu