# compiling kernel 3.x.x on ubuntu 20

Tags: cross-compiling, compatibility

I need to compile kernel 3.4 for armhf, and this requires gcc-4.9.
the cmd line is:
`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- tegra_defconfig` (here i'm not sure that I need to set CROSS_COMPILE)
`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-`

The issue is that I can't get ubuntu to use gcc-4.9, which is not available, I had to add xenial to the 'sources.list' file and now I have it on my system but am unable to use it.
Adding `CC=gcc-4.9` to the commands will then not use the `arm-linux-gnueabihf` prefix defined by `CROSS_COMPILE`.
`update-alternatives` does not recognise gcc-4.9 as a second c compiler. 
Does anyone see a way around this ?
Please don't just drop a comment like "install xenial".

Comment: You can try these commands before running ```make```: ```update-alternatives --set gcc "/usr/bin/gcc-4.9"``` and ```update-alternatives --set g++ "/usr/bin/g++-4.9"```. Don't forget to reverse that to the current version when you're ready.

Comment: Thanks but you might have answered before I edited: the output is:
`update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gcc`

Comment: @flappix my default compiler is gcc-9, I tried installing gcc-10 thinking that it might unlock the update-alternatives features to set it to 4.9 but even with gcc-10 installed I got the same error that I refer to in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

From this thread: [How to change the default GCC compiler in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu)

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 50
sudo update-alternatives --set gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.3-13ubuntu2) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

To stick to my case (cross compiling):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.9 50
sudo update-alternatives --set arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.9
```

for kernel 3.x.x and older perl is required, you can get past the errors with `perlbrew use perl-5.10.0`, after having done `perlbrew init` and  `perlbrew install perl-5.10.0` (read well the output of the last two commands).

NOTE that even when cross compiling you need to set the host's gcc to 4.9
because the configuration generator requires it.